# How to control cancellations with Simplify functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

`FullSimplify` only simplifies the result of the following calculation halfway, leaving a lot of $e^{x^2/v}$ and $e^{m^2/v}$ terms that could have been cancelled:

```
gau[x_, v_] = (1/Sqrt[2*Pi*v])*E^-((x^2)/(2*v));
f[x_] = gau[x - m, v]/2 + gau[x + m, v]/2;
FullSimplify[D[Log[f[x]], {v, 4}]]
```

I tried combinations of `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Expand`, and `PowerExpand`, and the cancellations don't happen.

**Question 1:** How can I make it to those cancellations?  Ultimately I'd like the entire expression with all the $e^{n\ x/v}$ replaced with $y^n$, but that's the next step after I solve this current problem.

**Question 2:** Maybe this is a *Meta* question, but is there a page somewhere (on this site or elsewhere) on tricks and hacks for simplifying expressions that *Mathematica* built-ins don't nail?  Or just how to get the simplifying juuuust the way you want it?  Controlling simplification and more complete simplification seem to be a recurring themes in SE questions.  Could such a page be started on SE if it doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 6):

```
gau[x_, v_] = (1/Sqrt[2*Pi*v])*E^-((x^2)/(2*v));

f[x_] = gau[x - m, v]/2 + gau[x + m, v]/2;

expr1 = FullSimplify[D[Log[f[x]], {v, 4}]];

expr2 = expr1 // ExpandAll // Simplify
```

> (1/((1 + E^((2*m*x)/v))^4*v^8))*    (24*(-1 + E^((2*m*x)/v))*
>           (1 + E^((2*m*x)/v))^3*m*v^3*x - 
>         96*E^((2*m*x)/v)*
>           (-1 + E^((4*m*x)/v))*m^3*v*
>           x^3 + 16*E^((2*m*x)/v)*
>           (1 - 4*E^((2*m*x)/v) + 
>              E^((4*m*x)/v))*m^4*x^4 + 
>         3*(1 + E^((2*m*x)/v))^4*v^3*
>           (v - 4*x^2) - 
>         12*(1 + E^((2*m*x)/v))^2*m^2*v^2*
>           ((1 + E^((2*m*x)/v))^2*v - 
>              12*E^((2*m*x)/v)*x^2))

```
expr3 = expr2 /. Power[E, Times[a_, m, Power[v, -1], x]] -> y^a
```

> (1/(v^8*(1 + y^2)^4))*    (24*m*v^3*x*(-1 + y^2)*
>           (1 + y^2)^3 + 3*v^3*(v - 4*x^2)*
>           (1 + y^2)^4 - 96*m^3*v*x^3*y^2*
>           (-1 + y^4) + 16*m^4*x^4*y^2*
>           (1 - 4*y^2 + y^4) - 
>         12*m^2*v^2*(1 + y^2)^2*
>           (-12*x^2*y^2 + v*(1 + y^2)^2))

```
expr2 == (expr3 /. y^a_ -> Exp[a*m*x/v]) == (expr3 /. y -> Exp[m*x/v])
```

> True

Comment: Perfect!  I didn't know about ExpandAll[].  This is an aspect of MMa is confusing.  Why do Expand[] and Simplify[] exist at all when in order to accomplish what they're supposed to accomplish, you usually have to use ExpandAll[] and FullSimplify[]?  Are there other functions in this family that a relative noob should read up on?

Comment: I recommend that you make greater use of the `See Also` section in the documentation. `Expand` points to `ExpandAll` (and vice versa).